# Ruby: What does the line "m = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}" accomplish that "Hash.new" doesn't?

Tags: ruby, hash, rack

While studying [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/317-rack-app-from-scratch?view=asciicast) I came across the following bit of source code from Rack:

```
def self.middleware
  @middleware ||= begin
    m = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}
    m["deployment"].concat [
      [Rack::ContentLength],
      [Rack::Chunked],
      logging_middleware
    ]
    m["development"].concat m["deployment"] + [[Rack::ShowExceptions], [Rack::Lint]]
    m
  end
end
```

My question is about the third line. What does passing the block `{|h,k| h[k] = []}` to `Hash.new` accomplish? I tried it in IRB and it doesn't seem to do anything different from a regular `Hash.new`:

```
2.0.0p247 :003 > m1 = Hash.new
 => {} 
2.0.0p247 :004 > m2 = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = []}
 => {} 
2.0.0p247 :005 > m1 == m2
 => true
```

... but I'm going to guess that the guys who wrote Rack know more about Ruby than I do. What's the reasoning behind including that block?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It allows you to define default value as an array

```
h = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
h[:a]        # => {:a=>[]}
h[:b] << 123 # => {:a=>[], :b=>[123]}
```

More examples are here: [Hash.new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-new)

Comment: Ahhh I get it... so `m["deployment"]` is immediately created as an Array, which is why you can call `.concat` on it? (That was going to be my next question.)

Comment: How is this different from `Hash.new([])`?

Answer (score 2):

This creates default object ([] in this case) as value for every key. It calls h1[:a] = [] implicitly resulting in addition of key in the hash.

```
h1 = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []} 
h1[:a] # = []
h1[:a].push(1) # = [1]
h1[:b] # = []
h1 #= {:a=>[1], :b=>[]}
```

This returns a single default object as value for all keys.

```
h1 = Hash.new([])
h1[:a] # = []
h1[:a].push(1) # = [1]
h1[:b] # = [1]
h1 #= {}
```

This returns default object as value for all keys. But does not add key to the hash.

```
h1 = Hash.new{[]}
h1[:a] # = []
h1[:a].push(1) # = [1]
h1[:b] # = []
h1 #= {}
```